# How to return to base function/script

Tags: function, matlab

Does anyone know how to return to a base function/script (f/s) when inside a f/s that's called by a f/s that was called by the base f/s? Confusing I know...

base f/s - f/s - f/s --> return from here to base f/s

The regular `return` call will only get me to the f/s one level above.

I'm currently using a `try-catch` construct in the base f/s to find when the program errors out, but I feel like this is a less than ideal way of doing this.

Thanks, and if I can clarify any other way please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I advise against using a `try` `catch` block to achieve this behavior, unless an actual error or exception has occurred. Going this route will result in code that isn't clear.

Instead, have the inner function return a value indicating some status. Then evaluate that status in the middle function to determine if the middle function should return as well.

Here is a simple example

```
function outer()
   middle();
end


function middle()

  innerResult = inner()

  switch innerResult
    case 1:
      disp('Executing the guts of middle()');
    case -1:
      return;
  end


end

function retVal = inner()
  if returnToOuter
    return -1;
  else
    return 1;
  end
end
```